# Hugging Face facebook/m2m100_418M model translates to Finnish instead of french

Tags: python, facebook, huggingface-transformers

I am using the transformers framework to load the facebook/m2m100_418M model, and for some reason, the translation is in Finnish. When it should be in french?

Is there a different model cached somewhere?

```
from transformers import M2M100ForConditionalGeneration, M2M100Tokenizer


model_name = 'facebook/m2m100_418M'
model = M2M100ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
tokenizer = M2M100Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)


# Translate a single message from English to French
source_text = "Hello, how are you?"
input_ids = tokenizer.encode(source_text, return_tensors='pt')
model.config.source_lang = "en"
model.config.target_lang = "fr"
output_ids = model.generate(input_ids)
translated_text = tokenizer.decode(output_ids[0], skip_special_tokens=True)
print(translated_text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the `pipeline` approach:

```
from transformers import pipeline

mt = pipeline("translation", model="facebook/m2m100_418M", 
              tokenizer="facebook/m2m100_418M", 
              src_lang="en", tgt_lang="fr")

mt("Hello, how are you?", max_length=50)
```

[out]:

```
[{'translation_text': 'Bonjour, comment vous êtes-vous ?'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

`facebook/m2m100_418M` is a seq2seq model that uses a special token to identify in which language it should translate. The approach therefore utilizes [forced_bos_token_id](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/m2m_100#training-and-generation):

```py
from transformers import M2M100ForConditionalGeneration, M2M100Tokenizer

source_text =  "Hello, how are you?"

model_id = "facebook/m2m100_418M"

model = M2M100ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_id)
tokenizer = M2M100Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)

# translate Hindi to French
tokenizer.src_lang = "en"
encoded_source = tokenizer(source_text, return_tensors="pt")
generated_tokens = model.generate(**encoded_source, forced_bos_token_id=tokenizer.get_lang_id("fr"))
tokenizer.batch_decode(generated_tokens, skip_special_tokens=True)
```

Output:

```
['Bonjour, comment vous êtes-vous?']
```